# django is not displaying media directory

Tags: python, django

I have this configuration

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'client/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                #Some dependencies
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

In my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'client'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    #some others urls
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My media is uploaded in my root project, in the directory `/media/` but, when I try to see those resources in the browser, are not displayed and return `404 error`.

What I have wrong in my configuration?

Comment: How are your BASE_DIR and PROJECT_ROOT setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the permission problem. Try:

```
 sudo chmod -R a+rw media
```